# Write lock being released without being held

Tags: c#, .net

I have a situation whereby ReadWriterLockSlim is throwing the exception "System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException - The write lock is being released without being held." when I try to execute ExitWriteLock(). As far as I can tell, this shouldn't happen because subsequent threads that enter the try block will 'block' until they can obtain the lock. Am I missing something here?

The issue looks very similar to [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/a6e21e9b-627d-426c-9d3e-0cca35e86aa1), however no solution was posted there.

```
//Code simplified for example. 

public class i18nService {
    internal static ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion);

    private string ProcessText()
    {
        try {
            cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
            return "xyz";
        }
        finally {
            cacheLock.ExitWriteLock(); // Error is throwing here. 
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks very much for your help :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    try {
        cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
        return "xyz";
    }
    finally {
        cacheLock.ExitWriteLock(); // Error is throwing here. 
    }
```

Q: What happens if `cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();` fails?

A: The `finally` statement gets executed.

- `cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();` gets called
- But we don't have the lock

Try this:

```
private string ProcessText()
{
    cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try {
        return "xyz";
    }
    finally {
        cacheLock.ExitWriteLock(); // Error is throwing here. 
    }
}
```

Presumably .NET is designed in such a way that if `EnterWriteLock()` fails, the lock is released (or never held at all).

Comment: G'day Brendan. Thanks for the response. I actually thought along a similar line but am not sure that it's the case. 
from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.enterwritelock.aspx
"This method blocks until the calling thread enters the lock, and therefore might never return. Use the TryEnterWriteLock method to block for a specified interval, and then return if the calling thread has not entered write mode during that interval."
However, as you point out, I am not allowing for an exception on EnterWriteLock()... hmmm... let me play with it some more.

Comment: I always wondered in all the examples the write lock was before the try statement, but never an explanation given. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 19):

But if an error is thrown trying to enter the lock, then it will execute finally, without holding it. Why not simply change to:

```
...
finally {
    if(cacheLock.IsWriteLockHeld)
        cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
}
...
```

Comment: Hi Petar. I think that you (and Brendan) are right. Cheers :-)