# C# 4.0 List<T> accessing with Where,Single,SingleorDefault from multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are IEnumerable Linq methods thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103779/are-ienumerable-linq-methods-thread-safe)

quick question. Will using Where,Single,SingleorDefault on a list while other threads access it (read but also write) cause collection changes while enumerating exception?

why doesn't the c# 4.0 have concurrent List?

Comment: I think you are not actually asking for a concurrent list but for a list with synchronized access: [`SynchronizedCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>` is safe to *read* from multiple threads, but doesn't support *writing* at all. So you can execute multiple LINQ queries against the list so long as they don't make any changes. You could use [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) to obtain a write lock only for times where you need to write.

> why doesn't the c# 4.0 have concurrent List?

I believe it's hard to create an implementation which keeps the same guarantees as `List<T>` in terms of ordering, but is also thread-safe *and* efficient. The concurrent collections in .NET 4 are efficient, at the cost of some guarantees (such as ordering in the case of [`ConcurrentBag<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks (Btw I really enjoy your blog)