# Thread safe with Linq and Tasks on a Collection

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Given some code like so

```
public class CustomCollectionClass : Collection<CustomData> {}
public class CustomData
{
    string name;
    bool finished;
    string result;
}

public async Task DoWorkInParallel(CustomCollectionClass collection)
{
    // collection can be retrieved from a DB, may not exist.
    if (collection == null)
    {
        collection = new CustomCollectionClass();
        foreach (var data in myData) 
        { 
            collection.Add(new CustomData()
            {
                name = data.Name;
            });
        }
    }

    // This part doesn't feel safe. Not sure what to do here.
    var processTasks = myData.Select(o => 
        this.DoWorkOnItemInCollection(collection.Single(d => d.name = o.Name))).ToArray();

    await Task.WhenAll(processTasks);

    await SaveModifedCollection(collection);
}

public async Task DoWorkOnItemInCollection(CustomData data)
{
    await DoABunchOfWorkElsewhere();
    // This doesn't feel safe either. Lock here?
    data.finished = true;
    data.result = "Parallel";
}
```

As I noted in a couple comments inline, it doesn't feel safe for me to do the above, but I'm not sure. I do have a collection of elements that I'd like to assign a unique element to each parallel task and have those tasks be able to modify that single element of the collection based on what work is done. End result being, I wanted to save the collection after individual, different elements have been modified in parallel. If this isn't a safe way to do it, how best would I go about this?

Comment: I assume `DoWorkOnItemInCollection` has at least one `await` inside it that you did not show, correct?

Comment: Yeah, this is very simplified. I'll add something in to have an await.

Comment: Your code won't compile, you can't use `await` in non-`async` method, like you do in `DoWorkInParallel`.

Comment: It's a typo, it's async. Fixed.

Comment: I assume `DoWorkInParallel` is called by a single thread, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is the right way to do this, assuming starting `DoABunchOfWorkElsewhere()` multiple times is itself safe.

You don't need to worry about your LINQ query, because it doesn't actually run in parallel. All it does is to invoke `DoWorkOnItemInCollection()` multiple times. Those invocations may work in parallel (or not, depending on your synchronization context and the implementation of `DoABunchOfWorkElsewhere()`), but the code you showed is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Your above code should work without issue. You are passing off one item to each worker thread. I'm not so sure about the async attribute. You might just return a Task, and then in your method do:

```
public Task DoWorkOnItemInCollection(CustomData data)
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
        DoABunchOfWorkElsewhere().Wait();
        data.finished = true;
        data.result = "Parallel";
    });
}
```

You might want to be careful, with large amount of items, you could overflow your max thread count with background threads. In this case, c# just deletes your threads, which can be difficult to debug later.

I have done this before, It might be easier if instead of handing the whole collection to some magic linq, rather do a classic consumer problem:

```
class ParallelWorker<T>
{
    private Action<T> Action;
    private Queue<T> Queue = new Queue<T>();
    private object QueueLock = new object();
    private void DoWork() 
    {
        while(true)
        {
            T item;
            lock(this.QueueLock)
            {
                if(this.Queue.Count == 0) return; //exit thread
                item = this.Queue.DeQueue();
            }

            try { this.Action(item); }
            catch { /*...*/ }
        }
    }

    public void DoParallelWork(IEnumerable<T> items, int maxDegreesOfParallelism, Action<T> action)
    {
        this.Action = action;

        this.Queue.Clear();
        this.Queue.AddRange(items);

        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        for(int i = 0; i < items; i++)
        {
            ParameterizedThreadStart threadStart = new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoWork);
            Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
            thread.Start();
            threads.Add(thread);
        }

        foreach(Thread thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

This was done IDE free, so there may be typos.

Comment: There is no advantage to using `Wait()` when you can `await`.

Comment: you can't use await, if your method isn't marked async, I removed async because I don't think linq supports that.

Comment: I'm talking about the code inside `Task.Run()` (using that is itself a questionable choice here). That doesn't have anything to do with LINQ and can certainly be made `async`.

Comment: And I didn't even notice your second suggestion of explicitly using `Thread`s. That's even worse.

Comment: I guess what was concerning me is that I was calling SIngle() on my collection, within a Select, to find the custom data associated to my data, and then modifying the custom data, which is a bit more parallelization than I'm used to since none of these collections are thread safe ([as discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103779/are-ienumerable-linq-methods-thread-safe)). But maybe I'm over-thinking this? Either way, thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: As long as you are not updating the collection itself, just fields of a member of a collection, you should have no issue.

Comment: @svick, you might need that depending on your solution. You can't abort Tasks for example.

Comment: @ohmusama You really, really shouldn't abort threads, it's incredibly unsafe. On the other hand, Tasks do support safe cancellation.

Comment: @svick, I agree, in general principle, but how would you do `File.Exists()` with a timeout using just a `Task`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make the suggestion that you use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main") to do this task.

Here's the code:

```
public void DoWorkInParallel(CustomCollectionClass collection)
{
    var query =
        from x in collection.ToObservable()
        from r in Observable.FromAsync(() => DoWorkOnItemInCollection(x))
        select x;

    query.Subscribe(x => { }, ex => { }, async () =>
    {
        await SaveModifedCollection(collection);
    });
}
```

Done. That's it. Nothing more.

I have to say though, that when I tried to get your code to run it was full of bugs and issues. I suspect that the code you posted isn't your production code, but an example you wrote specifically for this question. I suggest that you try to make a running compilable example before posting.

Nevertheless, my suggestion should work for you with a little tweaking.

It is multi-threaded and thread-safe. And it does do cleanly save the modified collection when done.

Comment: So, you're suggesting to use the "fire and forget" approach? That doesn't sound like a good choice to me here.

Comment: @svick - Why is this "fire and forget"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: You set up the observable, then you set up what happens when it completes, and then you immediately return. So `DoWorkInParallel()` will very likely return before `DoWorkOnItemInCollection()` or `SaveModifedCollection()` complete and any exceptions from those methods won't propagate to the caller.

Comment: @svick - That's a fair call. It wouldn't take much to fix this, but I didn't want to over complicate the solution. I still think that Rx is a way better way to do this kind of thing.