# Returning a Read-Only concurrent list

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering, assume I have a ConcurrentBag encapsulated in an object like this

```
class Package
{
   private ConcurrentBag<string> myList;
   public string title {get; private set;}
   public string description {get; private set;}

   public Package(string title,string description)
   {
       myList = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
       this.title = title;
       this.description = description;
   }


   public override string ToString()
   {
       return title + " " + description;
   }
}
```

How would I return a read-only version of my ConcurrentBag?

Comment: Do you want a read-only interface like [IReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542.aspx) or do you want it throw exceptions when `Add` is called, like [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) does?

Comment: I only want to return Read-Only collection of my ConcurrentBag, so I would guess IReadOnlyCollection.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you return a clone? I know it's not ideal but otherwise you will have to make your own custom `ConcurentBagReadOnly`.

Answer (score -2):

Since you're looking for functionality close to [IReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542.aspx) which only offers a `Count` property, I would expose it as `IEnumerable<string>` and rely on LINQ extensions to query it.

Comment: Good point, according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995266/how-to-create-a-thread-safe-generic-list) they are not.  You might be able to go the same route offered in an answer there and expose the functionality that you need to by wrapping calls to LINQ with locks.

Comment: Exposing original collection will give possibility to cast it to original type and modify its content.