# Powershell: Why is my variable empty after using ForEach-Object -Parallel?

Tags: powershell, foreach-object

I am trying to gather data from several servers using ForEach-Object -Parallel. The variable I use is being populated within the loop, but when the loop finishes the variable is empty.

```
$DBDetails = "SELECT @@VERSION"

$VMs = ("vm1", "vm2", "vm3", "vm4", "vm5", "vm6", "vm7")
$DBInventory = @()

$scriptBlock = {
    $vm = $_
    $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $vm -Query $using:DBDetails
    $DBInventory += $result
    Write-Host "Added $($result.Count) rows from $($vm)"
}

$VMs | ForEach-Object -Parallel $scriptBlock
Write-Host "Number of elements in DBInventory: $($DBInventory.Count)"
```

I expect the last line to return the number of elements gathered within the loop that executed on the previous line.  There should be a total of 7 elements, but I am left with none.

My result looks like this:

```
Added 1 rows from vm1
Added 1 rows from vm2
Added 1 rows from vm3
Added 1 rows from vm4
Added 1 rows from vm5
Added 1 rows from vm6
Added 1 rows from vm7
Number of elements in DBInventory: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ForEach-Object -Parallel` causes execution of the loop body *in a separate runspace*, meaning you don't have direct access to the variables defined in the calling scope.

To work around this, make two changes to your code:

- Use a collection type *other than* a resizable array (below I've use a generic `[List[psobject]]`)
- Reference the variable from the caller's scope with the `using:` scope modifier and assign to a local inside the block

The resulting local variable will then reference the same list-object in memory, and changes made to that list via its methods (`Add()`, `Remove()`, `AddRange()`, etc.) will be reflected anywhere else its referenced (including the original `$DBInventory` variable from your calling scope).

```
$DBDetails = "SELECT @@VERSION"

$VMs = ("vm1", "vm2", "vm3", "vm4", "vm5", "vm6", "vm7")
$DBInventory = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::new()

$scriptBlock = {
    $vm = $_
    $inventory = $using:DBInventory
    
    $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $vm -Query $using:DBDetails
    $inventory.AddRange([psobject[]]$result)
    Write-Host "Added $($result.Count) rows from $($vm)"
}

$VMs | ForEach-Object -Parallel $scriptBlock
Write-Host "Number of elements in DBInventory: $($DBInventory.Count)"
```

---

As [mklement0 notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75687634/712649), `[List[psobject]]` is **not thread-safe** - for production code you'll definitely want to pick a collection type that is, like for example a `[System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrenBag[psobject]]` - essentially an unordered list:

```
$DBInventory = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[psobject]]::new()
```

Beware that the `ConcurrentBag` type, as the name might suggest, *does not preserve insertion order*. If this is a problem, you may want to consider using a `[ConcurrentDictionary[string,psobject[]]]` - this way you can tie the query output back to the orignal input string:

```
$DBInventory = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary[string,psobject[]]]::new()
```

Since another thread may (hypothetically) have added an entry for the same key since you dispatched your call to `Add()`, the `ConcurrentDictionary` type requires us to use it slightly differently than a regular dictionary or hashtable:

```
$scriptBlock = {
    $vm = $_
    $inventory = $using:DBInventory
    
    $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $vm -Query $using:DBDetails
    $adder = $updater = { return Write-Output $result -NoEnumerate }
    $inventory.AddOrUpdate($vm, $adder, $updater)
    Write-Host "Added $($result.Count) rows from $($vm)"
}
```

Here, the concurrent dictionary will execute the `$adder` function on our behalf if the key doesn't already exist (otherwise it'll run the `$updater`), and the result will be assigned as the entry value.

You can subsequently access the entry values the same way you would a hashtable:

```
$DBInventory[$vms[-1]] # returns array containing the query results from the last VM in the list
```

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

- Use the **`$using:` scope** to **refer to the *value* of variables defined in the *caller*'s scope**, as you're partially already doing.
- You **cannot directly *modify* variables in the caller's scope** (`$using:DBInventory += $result` would *not* work), but you don't need to: **let PowerShell collect the output objects in an array for you**:

```
$DBDetails = "SELECT @@VERSION"

$VMs = ("vm1", "vm2", "vm3", "vm4", "vm5", "vm6", "vm7")
 = @()

$scriptBlock = {
    $vm = $_
    $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $vm -Query $using:DBDetails
    Write-Host "Outputting $($result.Count) rows from $($vm)"
    $result # Simply output the objects 
}

# Let PowerShell collect all output objects from the ForEach-Object -Parallel call 
# in an array.
# Note: The [array] type constraint ensures that $DBInventory is an array
#       even if there happens to be only *one* output object.
[array] $DBInventory = $VMs | ForEach-Object -Parallel $scriptBlock

Write-Host "Number of elements in DBInventory: $($DBInventory.Count)"
```

`$DBInventory` will contain a regular PowerShell array (`[object[]]`).

---

**Background information**:

- Your code already *partially* shows awareness that **you need the [`$using:` scope](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#using-local-variables) inside a script block that runs *in a different runspace*** (such as those in the *threads* that `ForEach-Object -Parallel` creates) in order to **refer to variable values from the *caller's* scope**.

  - This therefore in principle applies to your caller-side `$DBInventory` variable as well, however:

    - **A `$using:` reference is a reference to a variable *value*, not to a variable *itself*, so you cannot *assign to* `$using:` references**.
    - That is, `$using:DBInventory += $result` would *not* work, leaving aside the general point that using `+=` to "grow" arrays is best avoided due to its inefficiency - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375).
- While you ***could* initialize `$DBInventory` to an efficiently extensible *list type***, you'd **have to ensure that it is grown in *thread-safe manner***, given that you're using thread-based parallelism via `ForEach-Object -Parallel`:

  - Notably, the commonly used list types [`[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1) and [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) are *not* thread-safe.
  - You'd either have to:

    - add *manual synchronization code* to your script block, using .NET APIs, which is nontrivial.
    - pick a different, concurrent (thread-safe) collection type from the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent) namespace (there is none built in for *lists* as of .NET 8; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33086040/45375) offers a custom implementation)
    - use a thread-safe *wrapper*, e.g. `$DBInventory = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::Synchronized([System.Collections.Generic.List[object]] @())`, which returns a *non-generic* [`[System.Collections.IList]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IList) implementation.
      Note, however, that this is *inefficient*, due to the whole-list locking mechanism used - see [Thread-safe collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/#systemcollections-and-systemcollectionsgeneric); additionally, it doesn't expose an `.AddRange()` method for efficient appending of *multiple* elements, and its `.Add()` method *returns a (usually unwanted) value*, which you'll have to discard with `$null = ($using:DBInventory).Add(...)`
  - Note that the reason that growing lists via `$using:` *does* work - as opposed to via `+=` - is that you're adding elements via *methods* (`.Add()`, `.AddRange()`) of the *object* that is the *value* of the variable being referenced with `$using:`. That is, you're directly modifying the variable *value*, not the variable itself (which isn't supported).
- Fortunately, there's a **simpler solution**: Rely on **PowerShell's ability to *automatically* collect all output objects emitted by a pipeline in an array**, which is both more concise and more efficient than manual growth of a list, and also works with [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) `-Parallel`, as shown at the top - again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375) for background information.