# PowerShell Make ForEach Loop Parallel

Tags: powershell, foreach, parallel-processing, scriptblock, foreach-object

This is working code:

```
$ids = 1..9 
$status  = [PSCustomObject[]]::new(10)
foreach ($id in $ids)
{ 
   $uriStr      = "http://192.168." + [String]$id + ".51/status"
   $uri         = [System.Uri] $uriStr
   $status[$id] = try {Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -TimeOut 30}catch{}
}
$status
```

I would like to execute the ForEach loop in parallel to explore performance improvements.

First thing I tried (turned out naive) is to simply introduce the -parallel parameter

```
$ids = 1..9 
$status  = [PSCustomObject[]]::new(10)
foreach -parallel ($id in $ids)
{ 
   $uriStr      = "http://192.168." + [String]$id + ".51/status"
   $uri         = [System.Uri] $uriStr
   $status[$id] = try {Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -TimeOut 30}catch{}
}
$status
```

This results in the following error, suggesting this feature is still under consideration of development as of Powershell 7.3.9:

```
ParserError: 
Line |
   3 |  foreach -parallel ($id in $ids)
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The foreach '-parallel' parameter is reserved for future use.
```

I say naive because the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1) says the parallel parameter is only valid in a workflow.  However, when I try it I get an error saying workflow is no longer supported.

```
workflow helloworld {Write-Host "Hello World"}
ParserError: 
Line |
   1 |  workflow helloworld {Write-Host "Hello World"}
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Workflow is not supported in PowerShell 6+.
```

Then I tried various combinations from various references ([Good Example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/)), which advise about ForEach being fundamentally different from from ForEach-Object, which supports parallel, like so (basically piping the ids in):

```
$ids = 1..9 
$status  = [PSCustomObject[]]::new(10)
$ids | ForEach-Object -Parallel 
{ 
   $uriStr      = "http://192.168." + [String]$_ + ".51/status"
   $uri         = [System.Uri] $uriStr
   $status[$_] = try {Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -TimeOut 30}catch{}
}
$status
```

This generates the following error:

```
ForEach-Object: 
Line |
   3 |  $ids | foreach-object -parallel
     |                        ~~~~~~~~~
     | Missing an argument for parameter 'Parallel'. Specify a parameter of type
     | 'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock' and try again.

   $uriStr      = "http://192.168." + [String]$_ + ".51/status"
   $uri         = [System.Uri] $uriStr
   $status[$i_] = try {Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -TimeOut 30}catch{}
```

But, after trying various script block semantics, here is the best I could do (basically apply :using to status variable that is outside the script block):

```
$ids = 1..9 
$status  = [PSCustomObject[]]::new(10)
$myScriptBlock = 
{ 
   $uriStr      = "http://192.168." + [String]$_ + ".51/status"
   $uri         = [System.Uri] $uriStr
   {$using:status}[$_] = try {Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -TimeOut 30}catch{}
}
$ids | foreach-object -parallel $myScriptBlock
$status
```

Error, again:  Unable to index into Scriptblock

```
Line |
   4 |  … ng:status}[$_] = try {Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -TimeOut 30}catch{}
     |                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to index into an object of type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
InvalidOperation:
```

There are couple of other worthy to mention errors - if not applying the `:using` qualifier, get error

> "cannot index into null array"

this basically means the `$status` variable is unrecognizable in the foreach or script block.

All other ways to express the `:using` qualifier are rejected with errors like

> "assignment expression invalid"
> "use {}..."

so have been omitted for brevity and, better flow in problem statement.  Lastly, here is a reference on [SciptBlocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.3#using-script-blocks), for Powershell 7.3+ which have also been considered without much progress.

Comment: In your third code example - move the opening curly brace directly behind the parameter name `-Parallel`.  `$ids | ForEach-Object -Parallel  {`

Comment: @Olaf - thanks.  The suggestion does indeed change the error to  "Cannot index into a null array", which basically means variable $status is unrecognized inside the foreach -parallel loop block and therefore demands the use of script blocks, which in turn, leads to solution of introducing :using as in fourth code example, and same error: "unable to index into an object of type Scriptblock".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work as intended (see the `NOTE` source-code comment below):

```bash
$ids = 1..9 
$status  = [PSCustomObject[]]::new(10)
$ids | ForEach-Object -Parallel {  # NOTE: Opening { MUST be here.
   $uri = [System.Uri] "http://192.168.$_.51/status"
   # NOTE: (...) is required around the $using: reference.
   ($using:status)[$_] = try { Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -TimeOut 30 } catch {}
}
$status
```

<sup>Note: Since `$_` is used as the array index (`[$_]`), the results for your 9 input IDs are stored in the array elements starting with the *second* one (whose index is `1`), meaning that `$status[0]` will remain `$null`. Perhaps you meant to use `0..9`.</sup>

- You're using [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), in which PowerShell workflows [aren't supported anymore](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/01/10/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/); therefore, the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) *statement* doesn't support `-parallel` there.
- However, PowerShell 7+ *does* support `-Parallel` as a parameter of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*<sup>[1]</sup> for multi-threaded execution.

  - As without `-Parallel` (i.e. with the (often positionally bound) `-Process` parameter), the [script block (`{ ... }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) you pass as an argument to the cmdlet does *not* use a self-chosen *iterator variable* the way that you do in a `foreach` *statement* (`foreach ($id in $ids) ...`), but rather receives its input *from the pipeline* and uses  the [automatic **`$_`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) to refer to the input object at hand, as shown above.
  - Because the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet is a type of *command* - as opposed to a *language statement* such as `foreach` (or an *expression* such as `'foo'.Length`) - it is parsed in [*argument* (parsing) mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing#argument-mode):

    - A *command* must be specified on a *single line*, EXCEPT if:

      - explicitly indicated otherwise with a line continuation (placing a `` ` `` (the so-called backtick) at the *very end of the line*)
      - or the line is unambiguously *syntactically incomplete* and forces PowerShell to keep parsing for the end of the command on the next line.
    - *Language statements* (e.g., `foreach` and `if`) and *expressions* (e.g. .NET method calls), which are parsed in [*expression* (parsing) mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing#expression-mode), are generally *not* subject to this constraint.<sup>[2]</sup>
    - With a *script-block* argument, you can make a command multiline by using the syntactically-incomplete technique:

      - Placing its *opening `{` only* on the first line, allows you to place the block's content on subsequent lines, as shown above.
      - Note that the content of a script block is a new parsing context, in which the above rules apply again.
- In order to apply an operation to a [`$using:`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes#the-using-scope-modifier) reference (which accesses the value of a variable from the *caller's* scope) that *sets* a property or element identified by an *index* (`[$_]`), or *gets* a property value using an *expression* or an element using a *non-literal* index, or a *method call*, the `$using:` reference *must be enclosed in `(...)`*, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--).

  - Arguably, this shouldn't be necessary, but is as of PowerShell 7.3.9 - see [GitHub issue #10876](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10876) for a discussion.
  - As for your `{$using:status}[$_]` attempt: the `{...}` enclosure created a *script block*, which doesn't make sense here;<sup>[3]</sup> perhaps you meant to *delimit the identifier* part of the `$using:` reference, in which case the `{...}` enclosure goes *after* the `$`: `${using:status}`; however, that (a) isn't necessary here, and (b) doesn't help the problem - `(...)` around the entire reference is needed either way.
- A note on *thread safety*:

  - Because you're using an *array* to store your results, and because arrays are fixed-size data structures and you make each thread (runspace) target a dedicated element of your array, there is *no* need to manage concurrent access explicitly.
  - More typically, however, with variable-size data structures and/or in cases where multiple threads may access the *same element*, managing concurrency *is* necessary.
  - An *alternative* to filling a data structure provided by the caller is to simply make the script block *output* results, which the caller can collect; however, unless this output also identifies the corresponding input object, this correspondence is then lost.
  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75687634/45375) elaborates on the last two points (thread-safe data structures vs. outputting results).

---

<sup>[1] Somewhat confusingly, `ForEach-Object` has an [*alias*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) also named `foreach`. It is the *syntactic context* (the [parsing mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing)) that determines in a given statement whether `foreach` refers to the `foreach` *(language) statement* or the `ForEach-Object` *cmdlet*; e.g. `foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i }` (statement) vs. `1..3 | foreach { $_ }` (cmdlet).</sup>

<sup>[2] However, if an expression is syntactically complete on a given line, PowerShell also stops parsing, which amounts to a notable pitfall with `.`, the [member-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-): Unlike in C#, for instance, `.` must  be placed on the *same line* as the object / expression it is applied to. E.g. `'foo'.<newline>  Length` works, but `'foo'<newline>  .Length` does *not*. Additionally, the `.` must *immediately* follow the target object / expression even on a single line (e.g. `'foo'  .Length` breaks too)</sup>

<sup>[3] Due to PowerShell's unified handling of list-like collections and scalars (single objects) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44035802/45375) - indexing into a script block technically works with *getting* a value: indices `[0]` and `[-1]` return the scalar itself (e.g. `$var = 42; $var[0]`), all other indices return `$null` by default, but cause an error if `Set-StrictMode -Version 3` or higher is in effect; however, an attempt to *assign* a value *categorically fails* (e.g. `$var = 42; $var[0] = 43`)</sup>

Comment: YES, sir!  This is EXACTLY the solution I was looking for.  Thanks for the college of knowledge.  Tested on our system and it not only works but is also clearly performant, when scaled, knocking down the round trip from several minutes to a few seconds!

Answer (score 2):

I do not know about the parallel parameter of ForEach, but I do know you can use Jobs for parallel network requests, you could use the below example:

```
# Name of your jobs.
$JobName = "-StatusChecker"

# Holds the code we want to run in parallel.
$ScriptBlock = {
  param (
    $id
  )

  $uriStr      = "http://192.168." + [String]$id + ".51/status"
  $uri         = [System.Uri] $uriStr
  $response = try {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -TimeOut 30
  } catch {
    # Return a message for our results. Doesn't matter what you return but if it's null it will error.
    "Failed to grab status of ID: $id"
    # Write the error to the error stream but do not print it.
    Write-Error $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  }

  # The $Error variable contains a list of errors that occurred during the run.
  # By returning it, we get the opportunity to revise what went wrong in the job.
  return $Error, $response, $id
}

# Grab all remaining jobs from the last time this script was run, stop and remove them.
# If you don't do this then it will mess up your results for each session as they aren't removed.
# We identify the relevant jobs by the JobName parameter set with Start-Job.
Get-Job -Name "*$JobName" | Stop-Job
Get-Job -Name "*$JobName" | Remove-Job


$ids = 1..9 
# Iterate through each id and create a job for each one.
foreach ($id in $ids) {

  # The job runs in parallel.
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList @($id) -Name "ID-$ID-$JobName"
}

# Wait here until all jobs are complete.
$Jobs = Get-Job -Name "*$JobName" | Wait-Job

# Hold our results.
$status  = [PSCustomObject[]]::new(10)
# Grab the results of each job and format them into a nice table.
Foreach ($JobResult in $Jobs) {
  $Results = Receive-Job -Job $JobResult
  # $Results[0] is the error array returned by the job.
  # $Results[1] is $response from RestMethod.
  # $Results[2] is the $id.

  # Add returns to status list
  $Status[$Results[2]] = $Results[1]

  # Print each error found to the console.
  Foreach ($Err in $Results[0]) {
    Write-Error "Failed job for $($JobResult.Name). Error Message: $($Err)" -ErrorAction Continue
  }
}

# Final results.
$Status
```

Your code is inside the $ScriptBlock variable, most of the code below that is about retrieving the results from each job and processing them.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm your code worked on our system!   Just as I almost gave up and start learning python, Powershell redeemed itself.  I like what seems like a classic approach.

Comment: @NetDawg Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

This example works for me.  Arrays start from 0.  The curly brace needs to be on the same line after -parallel.

```
$ids = 0..9 
$status  = [PSCustomObject[]]::new(10)
$ids | foreach-object -parallel {
   $id = $_
   $mystatus = $using:status
   $mystatus[$id] = $id  # or  ($using:status) = $id
}
$status

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Alternatively just save the output, and not have to worry about it being thread safe:

```
$ids = 0..9 
$status = $ids | foreach-object -parallel {
  $id = $_
  $id
}
$status
```

Comment: I like this going back to the basics approach, and it was going to my next attempt to conjure up something like and build on it.  But kept thinking about Einstein who supposedly said, "make things as simple as possible, but no simpler" (lol)....  so I wanted to keep my code as gnarly as it could be reduced to (we have a much more complex situation realistically) so that I understood it all, especially the Powershell idiosyncrasies applicable.  But seems like an adaptation of this will also work just fine.  Will try it and report - if there are issues!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, but it is thanks only to minimalist brilliance of @js2010 and the amazing post by @Hugo (which I will keep as the accepted answer), that I could even fathom this.

```
$ids    = 0..9 | Get-Random -Shuffle
$status = $ids | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
   $uri = [System.Uri] "http://192.168.$_.51/status"
   try {Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -TimeOut 30}catch{}
} 
$status
```

Again, please first thoroughly read @Hugo first and then @js2010 as well.

Comment: Notes.  The shuffle was added to randomize id list to avoid any prioritization among ids.  Presumed/implied is that the Restful Status Response includes the ids or, better, the full uri, or both, in its response.  Otherwise, the status returned from REST call will need to typically be "enriched" with the id (for sure), and perhaps other helpful things like system timestamps etc.  Bottom line any realistic application will need to build on this bare bones illustration in many ways to be really useful.  And that is left as an exercise for the readers to customize.  Hint - Read @Hugo, again!